# Spherical Tensors (QM)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus

> Let $Q,Q'$ be defined by
>   $$Q=e\langle n,l,m=l|(3z^2-r^2)|n,l,m=l\rangle$$
>   $$Q'=e\langle n,l,m=l|(x^2-y^2)|n,l,m=l\rangle$$
>   Write $Q'$ using $Q'$ and corresponding Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.

I have the solution, but some of the steps are unclear to me.
First, we write the cartesian elements in spherical tensor form (using standard spherical harmonics tables) as follows:
$$3z^2-r^2=R_0^{(2)},\;x^2-y^2=\frac{1}{\sqrt6}\left( R_2^{(2)}+R_{-2}^{(2)}\right)$$
So far so good. What I did was to directly apply Wigner-Eckart theorem to $Q$ and $Q'$, noticing they are both related to the same 2nd-order tensor, thus they only differ by their corresponding Clebsch-Gordan coefficients and are comparable. But the solution continues as follows (up to contants which I neglect):
$$
\begin{align}
Q'(m')&=\langle n,l,m'|R_2 ^{(2)}+R_{-2}^{(2)}|n,l,m=l\rangle\\
&=\langle n,l,l-2|R_2 ^{(2)}|n,l,m=l\rangle \cdot \delta_{m',l-2}\tag{$\star$}\\
&=\langle n,l,l|R_0 ^{(2)}|n,l,m=l\rangle \cdot\frac{\langle l,2,l-2,2|l,2,l,l\rangle}{\langle l,2,l,0|l,2,l,l\rangle} \cdot \delta_{m',l-2}\\
&=Q\cdot\frac{\langle l,2,l-2,2|l,2,l,l\rangle}{\langle l,2,l,0|l,2,l,l\rangle} \cdot \delta_{m',l-2}
\end{align}$$
I didn't get step $(\star)$. I understand that the Kronecker delta means that $Q$ can't simultaneously be both terms, but:

a) why $R^{(2)}_2$ and not $R^{(2)}_{-2}$?

b) why is the delta $\delta_{m',l-2}$ and not $\delta_{m',l+2}$?

Using the direct application of Wigner-Eckart on $Q'$ with $m'=l+2$ I get that the above coefficient should be
$$\frac{\langle l,2,l,l+2|l,2,l,2\rangle}{\langle l,2,l,0|l,2,l,l\rangle} \cdot \delta_{m',l-2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the edit - much neater! Further, I realized $\delta_{m',l+2}$ is obviously impossible due to $-l\leq m\leq l$.

Comment: There are problems with your question as phrased: $Q'=O$ as this operator does not have diagonal components: since it is proportional to tensors with $M=\pm 2$ the $m$ values much change accordingly,  I addition, the $Q$ can also change $\ell $ by $2$ units. Also I think you are right about a): it should be $R_{-2}$.